# QDateTime::fromstring( __DATE__, "MMM d yyyy") returns invalid

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

Parsing the MSVC++ predefined `__DATE__` (maybe in conjunction with `__TIME__`) macro with QDateTime::fromstring() returns nothing (= an invalid QDateTime object). Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx:

> **DATE**      The compilation date of the current source file. The date
> is a string literal of the form Mmm dd yyyy. The month name Mmm is the
> same as for dates generated by the library function asctime declared
> in TIME.H.

The `dd` part seems to be filled with a leading space for days 1..9.

[QtDateTime::fromstring()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#fromString-2) only supports

```
d   the day as number without a leading zero (1 to 31)
dd  the day as number with a leading zero (01 to 31)
```

One solution might be to remove duplicate spaces from the `__DATE__` string prior to parsing, e.g. with [`QString::replace("  ", " ")`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#replace-8) and parse the day with the single `d`.

Comment: You can also clear the extra spaces in the middle with [QString::simplified](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#simplified). For example, `QDateTime::fromString(QString(__DATE__).simplified(), "MMM d yyyy)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
QLocale("en_US").toDate(QString(__DATE__).simplified(), "MMM d yyyy");
```

Comment: You should add some information why this is the answer.