# QDateTime from string (__DATE__) invalid

Tags: c++, qt, date

When im running the following code the qdatetime is invalid:

```
QString dateString = QString(__DATE__).simplified();
QDateTime date =  QDateTime::fromString(dateString, "MMM d yyyy");
qDebug() << "Build date " << date.toMSecsSinceEpoch();
```

The content of dateString = `Jul 14 2020` so there are no extra spaces.
Why is it not working.
The following code works fine:

```
qDebug() << "Build date 2" << QDateTime(QLocale("en_US").toDate(QString(__DATE__).simplified(), "MMM d yyyy")).toMSecsSinceEpoch();
```

It has the same date format and is also based on `__DATE__`.

The output is:

```
Build date  -3600000
Build date 2 1594677600000
```

My Complete code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDate>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString dateString = QString(__DATE__).simplified();
    QDateTime date =  QDateTime::fromString(dateString, "MMM d yyyy");
    qDebug() << "Build date " << date.toMSecsSinceEpoch();    
    qDebug() << "Build date 2" << QDateTime(QLocale("en_US").toDate(QString(__DATE__).simplified(), "MMM d yyyy")).toMSecsSinceEpoch();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I am running on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @waqar the result is that variable date is invalid, i was expecting it to be valid.

Comment: can you show the result? along with expected results?

Comment: @Waqar QDateTime date is literally invalid. I updated the answer to both contain a  datetime,.

Comment: It's working fine for me, both give the same output.

Comment: @Waqar I copied my complete source code.

Comment: Still not reproducible

Comment: Did you check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472735/qdatetimefromstring-date-mmm-d-yyyy-returns-invalid ?
The problem looks very similar (my apologies if it does not help).

Comment: @erel Yes I copied it from there but dont understand why the accepted answer is not working for me.

Comment: @Waqar than maybe it is based on some system setting.

Comment: Can you try `QLocale::system()` instead of `QLocale("en_US")` and tell what the output is?

Comment: The language of your OS is probably different than English. Qt expects that date will be provided in the OS language.

Comment: @Waqar that I get the same result as the first instance. (invalid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`QDateTime::fromString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qdatetime.html#fromString-1) (Qt 5.12) documentation:

> Note: Unlike the other version of this function, day and month names **must be given in the user's local language**. It is only possible to use the English names if the user's language is English.

Your system locale must be something other than English, so that's why it fails to work.